# Latex Table lines do not stretch along all columns

Tags: tables, sidewaystable

this is my first question with respect to Latex. I provided a code example below. Note that the variable names are not my real variable names and also the correlations table are not real. However, this is exactly how my correlation looks like, in terms of decimals and variable name length.

Question:

- When compiling the document, it is observed that the top and bottom lines do not stretch completely along the columns [Compile it yourself or see the image] -> is there a way to make these lines longer and be as long as there are columns [See image with desired results / red lines].
- A smaller font is not really an option because of readability reasons

Background:

- The tables are produced using the estout package in Stata
- The header names are altered: in a Normal correlation table  you the header names would equal the row names. However, this would make the table too big. Therefore, I chose to alter the header names to corresponding numbers
- EDIT: Note, this table is part of a whole document with pages before and after containing just regular text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Formatting tables 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{rotating}


\title{Sidewas ytest}
\author{x.y }
\date{June 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

%Table
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\scriptsize
\caption{Sample A: Correlation Matrix\label{tab:corr2}}
\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{15}{c}}
\toprule
                &(1)&(2)&(3)&(4)&(5)&(6)&(7)&(8)&(9)&(10)&11)&(12)&(13)&(14)&(15)\\
\midrule
(1) Variable name (\%)&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(2) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(3) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    0.051&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(4) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.1&    0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(5) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.5&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(6) Variable name (100s)&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(7) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.012&   -0.004&    0.008&   -0.000&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(8) Very Long Variable name &    0.005&   -0.071&   -0.045&   -0.161&   -0.104&   -0.005&   -0.003&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(9) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(10) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.056&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(11) Variable name &   -0.045&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.009&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(12) Variable name &   -0.133&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(13) Longer Variable name &    0.005&   -0.099&    0.033&   -0.000&    0.006&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.050&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.025&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(14) Long Variable name &    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.197&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.038&    1.000&         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(15) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.049&    0.018&   -0.085&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.026&    1.000\\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled table]

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Your table is wider than the textwidth, while the horizontal lines are as wide as the textwidth (See the warning message that the MWE creates: `Overfull \hbox (52.02281pt too wide) in alignment at lines 31--80`.

Comment: To overcome this, you can use `\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}` to slightly reduce the white space between adjacent columns (default is 6pt). Alternatively, you could also introduce (automatic) linebreaks in the first column (For this use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{15}{c}}` and the `tabularx` package.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!
@leandriis Thank you. I also saw that error. However, as I am very new to Latex and especially tables, any idea how I can fix this?
EDIT:  Thanks for the suggested solution. Can you point to me were I should replace the code with  your suggestion? (Especially the \scriptsize ```\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}``` suggestion

Comment: Instead of `\scriptsize` try with `\tiny`

Comment: @matthijsg: You can replace `\scriptsize` in your code with `\scriptsize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your table does not fit the available length of `\textheight` (with rotated tables the length switches too!).

To visualize this I added package `showframe` to your code. The lines are only inside the valid space for the table:

[image: table too wide]

To get the fit your table you can try the following possibilitys (now commented):

```
\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{15}{c}} % original
%\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}p{2cm}*{15}{c}} % <=========
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} % <=========================================
%\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{p{3.5cm}*{15}{c}} % <=========================
```

The complete mwe see please at the end of this post ...

The next possibility is to use `p{2cm}` instead your `l` gives you the result:

[image: small first column]

shows you the small (2cm) first column (see red arrow) and the last column does not go outside the typing area

[image: last colum]

but now the table is too long because some entries in the first column needs two lines to be completly printed.

The next possibility is to use

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} % <=========================================
\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{p{3.5cm}*{15}{c}} % <=========================
```

to get smaller space between all columns and to use a bigger space for the first column `p{3.5cm}`:

[image: biger first column]

That seems to be what you want but now we have still two possible issues: what should happen, if your variable names in the first column needs more place and what should happen, if your table goes again into the margin?

To get the width of the first column automatic calculates you can use package `tabularx` and environment `tabularx` to solve this. `X` marks the width of the column to be calculated:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for a better linebreaking and hyphenation in \RaggedRight
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight}X*{15}{c}}
```

To get an table spanning more than one page you can use `longtable`, if you need `tabularx` and `longtable` together use package `ltxtable` ... But I did not test if `longtable` or `ltxtable` are working in `sidewaystable` ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are three different suggestions on how to make your table fit into the textwidth:

1. Decrease the whitespace between adjacent columns by using `\setlenghth{\tabcolsep}{4pt}`
2. Decrease teh font size by replacing `\scriptsize` by `\tiny` ([As suggested by MadyYuvi in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497489/latex-table-lines-do-not-stretch-along-all-columns#comment1256184_497489))
3. Introduce automatic linebreaks in the first column using `tabularx`.

You can find the complete code for all three suggestions in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Formatting tables 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{rotating}


%%%%% Only needed for suggestion 3 %%%%%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Sidewas ytest}
\author{x.y }
\date{June 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

%Table
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{Sample A: Correlation Matrix\label{tab:corr1}}
\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{15}{c}}
\toprule
                &(1)&(2)&(3)&(4)&(5)&(6)&(7)&(8)&(9)&(10)&11)&(12)&(13)&(14)&(15)\\
\midrule
(1) Variable name (\%)&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(2) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(3) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    0.051&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(4) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.1&    0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(5) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.5&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(6) Variable name (100s)&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(7) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.012&   -0.004&    0.008&   -0.000&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(8) Very Long Variable name &    0.005&   -0.071&   -0.045&   -0.161&   -0.104&   -0.005&   -0.003&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(9) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(10) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.056&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(11) Variable name &   -0.045&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.009&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(12) Variable name &   -0.133&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(13) Longer Variable name &    0.005&   -0.099&    0.033&   -0.000&    0.006&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.050&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.025&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(14) Long Variable name &    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.197&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.038&    1.000&         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(15) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.049&    0.018&   -0.085&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.026&    1.000\\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\tiny
\caption{Sample A: Correlation Matrix\label{tab:corr2}}
\begin{tabular*}{1\hsize}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{15}{c}}
\toprule
                &(1)&(2)&(3)&(4)&(5)&(6)&(7)&(8)&(9)&(10)&11)&(12)&(13)&(14)&(15)\\
\midrule
(1) Variable name (\%)&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(2) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(3) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    0.051&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(4) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.1&    0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(5) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.5&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(6) Variable name (100s)&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(7) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.012&   -0.004&    0.008&   -0.000&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(8) Very Long Variable name &    0.005&   -0.071&   -0.045&   -0.161&   -0.104&   -0.005&   -0.003&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(9) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(10) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.056&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(11) Variable name &   -0.045&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.009&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(12) Variable name &   -0.133&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(13) Longer Variable name &    0.005&   -0.099&    0.033&   -0.000&    0.006&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.050&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.025&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(14) Long Variable name &    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.197&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.038&    1.000&         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(15) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.049&    0.018&   -0.085&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.026&    1.000\\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}


\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\scriptsize
\caption{Sample A: Correlation Matrix\label{tab:corr3}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\RaggedRight}X*{15}{c}}
\toprule
                &(1)&(2)&(3)&(4)&(5)&(6)&(7)&(8)&(9)&(10)&11)&(12)&(13)&(14)&(15)\\
\midrule
(1) Variable name (\%)&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(2) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(3) Variable name  (\%)&    0.5&    0.051&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(4) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.1&    0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(5) Variable name  (\%)&   -0.5&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(6) Variable name (100s)&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(7) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.012&   -0.004&    0.008&   -0.000&   -0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(8) Very Long Variable name &    0.005&   -0.071&   -0.045&   -0.161&   -0.104&   -0.005&   -0.003&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(9) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(10) Variable name &   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.056&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(11) Variable name &   -0.045&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.009&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(12) Variable name &   -0.133&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    1.000&         &         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(13) Longer Variable name &    0.005&   -0.099&    0.033&   -0.000&    0.006&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.050&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.025&   -0.000&    1.000&         &         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(14) Long Variable name &    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&    0.197&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.005&   -0.038&    1.000&         \\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\addlinespace
(15) Variable name &   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.049&    0.018&   -0.085&   -0.005&    0.005&   -0.005&    0.005&    0.005&    0.026&    1.000\\
                &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```